# Freeze an application intentionally in VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, windows, freeze

In order to test some features of my program I need a Windows application that freezes. Do you know a piece of code that can intentionally freeze the application (just like when they become inactive and you have to forcefully close them).

I need to do this in VB.NET (or C++, if possible). Also, the application must not crash, only freeze (stop responding)

Comment: How about an infinite loop?

Comment: I can not do it on purpose. However, till the end of the day it should happen  once or twice with me and I am going to post you the code :D

Comment: A recursive function

Comment: @Jaxedin It would leads to StackOverFlow

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Oh, I did it once and it freeze... So a `while true ... do` is the way to go.

Comment: The `while true ... do` does it. I just have to click a few times on the window and it stops responding, just like I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `Stop`, which suspends execution.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6acc062s.aspx

Comment: _"This is true regardless of whether the code was compiled in debug or retail mode."_ lol "retail mode"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
MsgBox("Displaying a message, which will stop execution until it is clicked OK.")
```

or, if you need to load your system:

```
For i = 0 To 2400   ' dimensioning the loop for 2 min in case _
                    ' it will block the PC completely
    Sleep(50)       ' give the system a space to breathe; need experimenting
Next i
```

still, it might be not enough for the purpose you need, but maybe it is what your're looking for...

Comment: That doesn't make the application stop responding.